# Como recarregar uma pagina sem perder inputfile

Tags: input

Olá, eu tenho um código me PHP onde eu uso `simplexml_load_file` para ler um xml porem nesta mesma pagina eu preciso enviar um formulário com `submit`, Meu problema é que ao enviar este `form` os dados do xml são perdidos. E eu gostria de saber como eu posso manter meu xml e enviar o `submit`?

OBS: já tentei usar `$_SESSION` para armazenar o endereço do arquivo mais não funcionou.

**Teste.php**

```php
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Projeto GP </title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <pre>
    <?php 
        print_r($_POST); 
    ?>
    </pre>
    <?php
    
        #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $myfile2 = $_FILES['XML']['tmp_name'];
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($myfile2);
        $frutas_array = $xml 
        #Recebe o XML e le ele 
        #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ?>
    <div>
        <form id ="form4.2" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
        <?php 
            foreach($frutas_array as $key => $fruta):
            #recuperando dados do xml atraves de um foreach
            #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ?>
            <label>A fruta é <?= $fruta ?></label>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?= $fruta ?>" name="frutas[<?= $key ?>][nome]">
            <input type="" name="frutas[<?= $key ?>][cor]">
            <!--criação de inputs a cada item do foreach -->
        <?php 
        endforeach 
        #finalizando o foreach apos a criação do formulario
        #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="">
        <!--submit com direção para esta propria pagina -->
        </form>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: não pode no lugar o caminho do arquivo, ler o arquivo no php e salvar o que interessa na session? pode até fazer um parse do xml para uma classe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

William, se entendi o que quer fazer, crie 2 formulários distintos na mesma página: um para enviar o XML e o outro para o submit das frutas. Cada um com seu próprio botão de envio. Assim, na primeira interação o usuário seleciona o XML e envia para o servidor. Então o servidor processa e cria o segundo formulário e na segunda interação o usuário coloca as cores e envia de novo e o servidor processa o segundo submit.

Se você precisa muito do arquivo enviado, use as funções do PHP para criar uma cópia dele. Salve na sessão o endereço desta cópia.

**Edição**:

Para guardar facilmente o XML na sessão, leia o arquivo enviado com `file_get_contents`. Ele vai retornar uma string com o conteúdo do XML. Guarde esse retorno em `$_SESSION`.

Ao invés de usar `simplexml_load_file` use `simplexml_load_string` usando o retorno dado por `file_get_contents` ou `$_SESSION`, dependendo de qual existir.

Lembrando que deverá fazer as verificações necessárias, e em algum momento limpar o valor guardado na sessão.

**Fim edição**

---

Analisando o código, você usou o `$frutas_array` no `foreach` mas em nenhum lugar você inicializou ele.

O mais perto que encontrei foi `$xml = $frutas_array` está invertido?

É importante lembrar que o método `simplexml_load_file` retorna [SimpleXMLElement](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.simplexmlelement.php). Não é Array mas implementa Traversable, então pode ser usado no foreach.

Dependendo da estrutura do XML você precisará acessar o método `children` para chegar no nível que contem a lista de frutas. Exemplo:

```
$frutas_array = $xml->children()->children();
```

Veja mais informações em [children](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/simplexmlelement.children.php).

Se gostar de ser visual, adicione o seguinte antes do foreach para ver o que está "chegando":

```
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($frutas_array); echo '</pre>';
```

PS:
Em algumas instalações do PHP todos os alertas e erros são suprimidos para não vazar informações importantes. Em alguns desses casos, adicionar `error_reporting(6143);` no início do script ativa os alertas. Em outros casos apenas alterando a configuração do PHP. As vezes isso pode ajudar a verificar o que está acontecendo.

Comment: sim realmente foi um equivoco meu o `$xml = $frutas_array` esta invertido e ja editei, porem toda a parte de ler o xml e mostrar o conteúdo dele esta funcionando perfeito mais quando eu envio `form` esse descarregamento da pagina me faz perder o xml

Comment: Ele some porque não foi enviado novamente, mas você guardou os dados dele no array "frutas" que é enviado no POST. Mas se quer guardar o arquivo original para reuso, vou editar a resposta com possibilidade de guardar na sessão.

Answer (score 2):

Isso não é possível de ser feito por questões de segurança. A ação de selecionar o arquivo tem que ser feita manualmente pelo usuário.

Para ficar mais claro imagine a seguinte situação: eu dono do site crio um form com um input file e no value desse input eu coloco um caminho de um arquivo bem genérico, por exemplo: C:/Documentos/senhas.txt, e adiciono um javascript para executar o submit do form automaticamente. Eu conseguiria o arquivo do computador da pessoa sem ela saber.

Comment: eu entendi o que disse porem o usuário já teria selecionado manualmente o arquivo anteriormente então eu so utilizaria de novo o mesmo arquivo